# How can I draw a cartesian reference system with X and Y axes centered, passing through the origin of the plot?

Tags: plot, octave, axes

I would like to draw using Octave the axis passing both through the origin (0,0) of my plot like in the figure below:
[image]

In matlab there is [axescenter](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22956-axescenter) that do exactly what I want. My brother told me to use this:

```
line(xlim,[0 0], 'linestyle', '--')
```

And something similar for y axis.

But I wonder if there is something better that gives me exactly the result shown in the image I've posted.

This is the sample curve:

```
ezplot(@(x,y) x.^2 -x.*8 -y.+ 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Noob here, I stumbled upon the answer:

- `set (gca, "xaxislocation", "origin");`
- `set (gca, "yaxislocation", "origin");`
- `box off` (if you want to)

Here's the documentation: https://docs.octave.org/v4.2.2/Axes-Properties.html